# "Cannot read property 'top' of null" on clicking 'Day' button

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I've been using [Fullcalendar](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar), everything is OK except when I try to go to a 'day' view (e.g. by clicking the 'day' button on the top right, or clicking on a specific date in the calendar), I'll get the following error (and the day will be shown as empty with no events even if it should have events), could you please give me any hints as to what the problem could be / how to solve it?

I'm using the latest version of Fullcalendar, v3.9.0. Thanks!

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null
at t.getTopPosition (momentfullcalendar.js:15)
at e.computeTimeTop (momentfullcalendar.js:18)
at e.computeInitialDateScroll (momentfullcalendar.js:18)
at e.applyScroll (momentfullcalendar.js:14)
at e.applyQueuedScroll (momentfullcalendar.js:14)
at e.popScroll (momentfullcalendar.js:14)
at e.onRenderQueueStop (momentfullcalendar.js:14)
at e (momentfullcalendar.js:13)
at e.dispatch (all1.js?v=40:3)
at e.q.handle (all1.js?v=40:3)
```

Here's my calendar code:

```
   var ev = [];

        $('.cal-class-data').each(function(){
            var title = $(this).attr('data-name');
            var start = $(this).attr('data-time');
            var s = new Date(start.replace(/-/g, '/'));
            var end = moment(s).add($(this).attr('data-duration'), 'm');
            var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
            var className = ['all-classes', 'sub-' + $(this).attr('data-sub'), 'cat-' + $(this).attr('data-cat')];
            var x = {title: title,start: s,end: end,url: url, className: className};
            ev.push(x);
        });


var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header:
                {
                    left: 'prev,next',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: opt
                },
            titleFormat: 'MMM D YYYY',
            defaultView: 'month',
            allDaySlot:false,
            navLinks:true,
            minTime: $('#min_hour').text() + ":00:00",
            maxTime: $('#max_hour').text() + ":00:00",
            firstDay:1,
            eventBackgroundColor:'#31B39D',
            eventBorderColor: 'white',
            height:'auto',
            events: ev,
        });
```

Comment: please show us your calendar code, thanks.

Comment: @ADyson - sure, I've just added the relevant code, thanks

Comment: there are still a few unknowns. Given this particular error message, I'd like to know the content of `$('#min_hour')` and `$('#max_hour')`, specifically.

Comment: I would recommend filing an issue on Full calendar though likely one of your parameters is null/undefined check _all_ of them

Comment: @Downgoat personally I wouldn't recommend to raise a bug with fullCalendar until we can be 100% certain it's not the OP's code which is causing the issue. Since we are still missing some information, we can't be sure, however, since there are some variables (of unknown, to us, value) involved in defining the min and max times, and the error message looks related to the calendar trying to set its starting scroll position based on those times.

Comment: Thanks ADyson for the hint - that was actually the problem - I've fixed those variables and it's now working